# Make point markers lead to a webpage link on click using Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, markers

I would like to make my map markers lead to a webpage link on click but I'm not quite sure how to make that happen.

I'm looking for a way to make my point marker lead to a link on click, rather than a link showing up in the pop-up. So the user clicks on the point marker and is led to a webpage in a new tab. How can I do this?

```
    //create variable to hold the map element, give initial settings to map
let map = L.map("map", {
  center: [38.1, -98],
  zoom: 5,
  //crs: crs,
});

//create basemap layer
let osm = L.tileLayer(
  "https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png",
  {
    attribution:
      '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>',
    subdomains: "abcd",
  }
);

//add to map
osm.addTo(map);

//create data variable
let data = [
  { coord: [40.308746567390294, -105.08229135535235], desc: "Berthoud, CO" },
  { coord: [39.74102996214569, -104.97940776843281], desc: "Denver, CO" },
  { coord: [30.138432902431312, -81.47832258872786], desc: "Jacksonville, FL" },
  { coord: [41.879448988274895, -87.6315117046291], desc: "Chicago, IL" },
  { coord: [41.8007476149432, -88.07480791524236], desc: "Lisle, IL" },
  { coord: [39.77999819036976, -89.64469580209537], desc: "Springfield, IL" },
  { coord: [38.04604579443191, -84.50244254581874], desc: "Lexington, KY" },
  { coord: [41.472330129058626, -87.06337336083872], desc: "Valparaiso, IN" },
  { coord: [39.77172821881897, -86.15817364592962], desc: "Indianapolis, IN" },
  { coord: [41.26104429429596, -95.8669285068911], desc: "Council Bluffs, IA" },
  { coord: [42.36045708792693, -71.05470762310003], desc: "Boston, MA" },
  { coord: [39.96068992182012, -82.99568108206131], desc: "Columbus, OH" },
  { coord: [41.499389586400504, -81.68319302542062], desc: "Cleveland, OH" },
  { coord: [33.999310722137295, -81.04237043257584], desc: "Columbia, SC" },
  { coord: [44.51263315662531, -88.01247710457417], desc: "Green Bay, WI" },
  { coord: [43.060874543136336, -88.1066145780849], desc: "Brookfield, WI" },
];

var logo = L.icon({
  iconUrl:
    "https://d2q79iu7y748jz.cloudfront.net/s/_squarelogo/8ec294c2f144d43bf5d7ec5f4f96d0c9",
  iconSize: [20, 20],
  iconAnchor: [10, 20],
  tooltipAnchor: [0, -20],
});

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  L.marker(data[i].coord, {
    icon: logo,
    alt: "Patrick Engineering logo",
    title: "Click for more info",
    riseOnHover: true,
  })
    .addTo(map)
    .bindTooltip("<h3>" + data[i].desc + "</h3>", { direction: "top" });
}
```

Comment: Not quite. I'm looking for a way to make my point marker lead to a link on click, rather than a link showing up in the pop-up. So the user clicks on the point marker and is led to a webpage in a new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating marker you can set `click` event processing function for the marker and within it open new browser tab with `window.open` method. To get the specific URL for the marker it would be the best to expand data with the `url` property. You bring `url` property to click processing function through custom option `myUrl`. Name can be any, as long as it does not interfere with the standard Leaflet options.

Relevant code could then look something like this:

```
let data = [
  { coord: [40.308746567390294, -105.08229135535235], desc: "Berthoud, CO", url: 'https://www.berthoud.org/' },
  { coord: [39.74102996214569, -104.97940776843281], desc: "Denver, CO", url: 'https://www.denver.org/' },
  .
  .
  .
];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  L.marker(data[i].coord, {
    icon: logo,
    alt: "Patrick Engineering logo",
    title: "Click for more info",
    riseOnHover: true,
    myUrl: data[i].url
  })
    .addTo(map)
    .bindTooltip("<h3>" + data[i].desc + "</h3>", { direction: "top" })
    .on('click', function(evt) {
      window.open(evt.target.options.myUrl, '_blank');
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test the solution. Reference `data[i].url` does not work inside event processing function. See modified answer (tested).

Comment: I rolled your question back to original, otherwise answer makes no sense to somebody who does not know the history of communication.

Comment: Thank you so much!